# I'm trying to sort my files by date, how can I get the result into a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableview` that's is been filled with .csv files from document directory. So far I'm able to get the date and sort them but not sure how to get the result in to an array and then into the `tableview`.

EDIT: i'm able to get it into an array but now when i try to get the files in the table view i got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c00ba040'
```

Code:
--data
    NSMutableArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableArray*   fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
//--- Listing file by name sort
NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);

//---- Sorting files by extension
NSMutableArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF EndsWith '.csv'"];
filePathsArray =  [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"\n\n Sorted files by extension %@",filePathsArray);
```

///

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

```
////gettime

NSArray  *paths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* fullPath = [paths3 objectAtIndex:0];
fullPath = [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"%@", fullPath);

NSMutableArray *titleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *fileDataString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *linesArray=[fileDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\,"];


int k=0;
for (id string in linesArray)
    if(k<[linesArray count]-1){

        NSString *lineString=[linesArray objectAtIndex:k];
        NSLog(@"%@",lineString);
        NSArray *columnArray=[lineString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\,"];
        [titleArray addObject:[columnArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        k++;

    }


NSLog(@"%@",[titleArray objectAtIndex:1]);



UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



cell.textLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:1 ];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(0.0/255.0) blue:(0.0/255.0) alpha:1];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];

cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(235.0/255.0) green:(120.0/255.0) blue:(33.0/255.0) alpha:1];



return cell;
```

}

////

```
- (IBAction) sortBydate: (id) sender
{

    NSError *err;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                      inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                             appropriateForURL:nil
                                                        create:false
                                                         error:&err];
    NSMutableArray *files = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentDirectoryURL
                                        includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLCreationDateKey]
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&err] mutableCopy];

    [files sortUsingComparator:^(NSURL *lURL, NSURL *rURL) {
        id lDate = [lURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLCreationDateKey] error:nil][NSURLCreationDateKey];
        id rDate = [rURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLCreationDateKey] error:nil][NSURLCreationDateKey];
        return [lDate compare:rDate];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", files);


      self.dirList = [files mutableCopy];
    //
        self.data.reloadData;
   // NSLog(@"Sorted Array : %@",filePathsArray);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is outdated. As you are using `FileManager` anyway use the modern URL related API `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`

Your code uses `NSMutableDictionary` which is useless because dictionaries are unordered.

To sort URLs you have to write a comparator which gathers and compares the  `NSURLCreationDateKey` resource.

The code make the `files` array mutable and sorts the URLs in place.

```
NSError *err;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                  inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                         appropriateForURL:nil
                                                    create:false
                                                     error:&err];
NSMutableArray *files = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentDirectoryURL
                           includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLCreationDateKey]
                                              options:0
                                                error:&err] mutableCopy];

BOOL ascending = YES;

[files sortUsingComparator:^(NSURL *lURL, NSURL *rURL) {
    NSDate *lDate, *rDate;
    [lURL getResourceValue:&lDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
    [rURL getResourceValue:&rDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
    return ascending ? [lDate compare:rDate] : [rDate compare:lDate];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", files);
```

Comment: awesome thanks! now i'm try to get the files in the table view but i'm getting a error , code: 
 self.dirList = [files mutableCopy]; 
self.data.reloadData;

error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c00ba040'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Edit the question and add the relevant code. The error message reveals that somewhere a string API is used but the receiver is an URL.

Comment: Thanks, how con i fix that?

Comment: Probably you are assiging the URL directly to a text property of a label. You can't do that, an URL is not a string. assign `url.lastPathComponent` or `url.absoluteString`. You should use lightweight generics in ObjC, then the compiler helps you to avoid those errors at compile time.

Comment: Make sense, Okay i see that lastPathComponent returns the file name, but not sure how to implemented in the code how can i do it? Thanks

Comment: In **what** code? Your issue is not related to the code in the question and answer and nobody can read you mind 

Comment: Please explain what you are going to accomplish. I have no clue. My code sorts an array of URLs nothing else.

Comment: Okay, i have a uitableview that the cell's are been filed with .csv files that are in documents directory. I want to do a button that sort the files by date ascending and descending in the tableview, let me know is i was clear and thanks for your time :) i'm a beginner.

Comment: You can use the `files` array as data source array and display the file name in the cells. You can reuse also the sort comparator but you need to add a parameter to be able to sort ascending and descending. Then in the button IBAction sort the array and reload the table view. I updated the answer adding the `ascending` parameter. However it would be more efficient to create a custom class to avoid pulling the URL resources over and over.

Comment: okay, got it.   How do i use the files array as data source? when i try to fill the table view i get the error i posted before :
dirList is the array to fille the text label in the cell and data is the tableview i place this code at the end. 
  self.dirList = [files mutableCopy];
  self.data.reloadData;

Comment: Once again: **Add the relevant code** (declaration and initialization of the data source array and `cellForRow`)