# How to get only the filename of a NSUrl array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array of `NSUrl` but I only need the filename of each path to show up in a tableview text label cell.

I'm getting the files from documents directory and filtered the `.csv` files that are the ones I need to show up in the table view's cell.

Here is my code:

```
        NSError *err;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                          inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                 appropriateForURL:nil
                                                            create:false
                                                             error:&err];

        NSMutableArray *files = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentDirectoryURL
                                            includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLCreationDateKey ]
                                                               options:0
                                                                 error:&err] mutableCopy];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension='.csv'"];
        NSArray *csvFiltered = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

////////////


NSMutableArray*allItems = [NSMutableArray new];

  for (NSURL*paramURL in csvFiltered)
        {
            NSString *basenameOnly = documentDirectoryURL.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension;


           [allItems addObject:basenameOnly];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", allItems);
        self.dirList = [allItems mutableCopy];

        self.data.reloadData;
    }


        BOOL ascending = YES;
        [files sortUsingComparator:^(NSURL *lURL, NSURL *rURL) {
            NSDate *lDate, *rDate;
            [lURL getResourceValue:&lDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
            [rURL getResourceValue:&rDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
            return ascending ? [lDate compare:rDate] : [rDate compare:lDate];
        }];
```

Comment: check my answer... hope that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I have a [déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346939/im-trying-to-sort-my-files-by-date-how-can-i-get-the-result-into-a-table-view/48347245#48347245)

Second of all **do not** *get only the filename of a NSUrl array*. You will lose the ability to sort the files by creation date.

---

You cannot filter an array of `NSURL` with a predicate, you must filter the files in a loop.

To use the filtered array as a data source first create a property in the .h file

```
@property NSMutableArray<NSURL *> *files;
```

In the .m file create a separate method to sort the files

```
- (void)sortFilesByCreationDateAscending:(BOOL)ascending
{
    [self.files sortUsingComparator:^(NSURL *lURL, NSURL *rURL) {
        NSDate *lDate, *rDate;
        [lURL getResourceValue:&lDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
        [rURL getResourceValue:&rDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
        return ascending ? [lDate compare:rDate] : [rDate compare:lDate];
    }];
}
```

Get the files, filter them and sort them in `viewDidLoad`. Then reload the table view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]:
    self.files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                      inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                             appropriateForURL:nil
                                                        create:false
                                                         error:nil];

    NSArray<NSURL *> *fileURLs = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentDirectoryURL
                                                    includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLCreationDateKey]
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
    if (error) { 
       NSLog(@"%@", error); 
       return; 
    }
    for (NSURL *anURL in fileURLs) {
        if ([anURL.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"csv"]) {
            [self.files addObject: anURL];
        }
    }
    [self sortFilesByCreationDateAscending:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return `self.files.count`

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` get the URL for the index path and display the file name

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];
    NSURL *url = self.files[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = url.lastPathComponent;
    return cell;
}
```

To sort the files in the other direction call `sortFilesByCreationDateAscending` with appropriate BOOL value and reload the table view.

Comment: I'm getting a error in this line
 NSArray<NSURL*> *fileURLs = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentDirectoryURL...
I think is a syntax error xcode telling me that is expecting a :

Comment: By bad, a line has disappeared. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Working good! also there is way to get only the date-hour in a string i didn't find any function to do that?

Comment: Yes, with `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to exclude .csv [ 4 characters ] for every item in the array

```
NSMutableArray*allItems = [NSMutableArray new];

 for ( NSURL* paramURL in csvFiltered )
 {
     NSString*fullfileWithExten = [paramURL lastPathComponent];

     NSString*filename = [fullfileWithExten substringToIndex:[fullfileWithExten length]- 4];

     [allItems addObject:filename];
 }
```

Comment: weird i print it the allItems array and i just got blank.

Comment: `- 4];` is very dangerous... extension can be of size 2,3,4... anything...

Comment: @FahimParkar it's applied to csvFiltered  which is .csv extension not files array

Answer (score 0):

Both [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc) and [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc) have properties which return back parts of a file path. So given a file URL:

```
NSURL *itemURL = ...
```

the last component of the path without the extension is simply given by:

```
NSString *basenameOnly = itemURL.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension;
```

where `NSURL`'s `lastPathComponent` strips off any directories leaving just the final file component, and `NSString`'s `stringByDeletingPathExtension` then strips of the extension.

HTH

Comment: Hey thanks! this looks cleanear i'm trying to implemented in the code but not luck. How do i make it to affect all the array? and make it return and array with the filenames?

Comment: One way is to write a standard `for`/`in` loop and build a new mutable array as you go.

Comment: I try like the one is beloved but i donn't get print the new array and dosn't contain any data.

Comment: i edited the code in the question, i added the for. Is okay like that? Thank

Comment: At a quick glance you've made at least one typo - mixing up variables - but yes, that is an outline for a standard `for`/`in` loop to iterate over an array and create a new one. *You shouldn't edit your question to show the answer as that will confuse people searching for an answer to the same question. You can revert the edit.*